# Can anyone identify this labrynth/marble maze?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

I have been advised it may be from the 70s, but I'm looking for any more specific info such as manufacturer. I can't find any information on the item at all.

Comment: It may be a custom build from a local woodworker. Curious how you acquired it and if the person you got it from could provide any more details.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an older variant of the game ["Labarynth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(marble_game)).  The modern ones, made by Brio, look like this: https://www.brio.us/products/by-age/6-years-and-up/labyrinth.

The goal is to get a marble from the start (on your board, one of the corners) to the end (on your board, the crown in the middle) without it falling in any of the holes, purely by manipulating the knobs on the sides.  The knobs tilt the board on the horizontal and vertical axes, causing the marble to roll in the direction of the tilt.  If the marble falls into a hole, there should be a spot on the side of the board where it will come out so that you can start over.

Brio did at some point make a round variant, whose pattern is closer to what you have: [image]

Comment: The question already indicates it is a version of labyrinth. He's looking for some information specific to that specific model.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson The way the question is phased, "labyrinth" is just used in the colloquial sense of "a maze", as indicated by the phrasing "labarynth/marble maze".   My answer indicates that "Labyrinth" is in fact the name of the game as well as the concept.

Comment: "I am looking for more specific info, such as the manufacturer." (And Brio didn't make the one in the pics).